# create list object from query result?

Tags: c#, json, linq

here my query result and class, i want list of how to create list object of "customer" with list "contract" is a property

```
customer contract_id number_of_products 
1        HD2         1000 
1        HD3         4500 
1        HD4         20000 
2        HD5         70 
2        HD6         8000
3        HD7         660
3        HD8         2200



    public class customer 
    {
        public string customer { get; set; }
        public List<contract> ls_contract{ get; set; }
    }
    public class contract
    {
        public string contract_id{ get; set; }
        public string number_of_products { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Please write us a little sample program that populates the sample input data. Then specify the expected output you want to receive based on that input data.

Comment: What is the actual json format that you have (at least you tagged json even though your data looks mor elike a DB table)? What what you tried?.. Hint `GroupBy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to follow C# coding convention:

```
public class Customer 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }
}

public class Contract
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string NumberOfProducts { get; set; }
}
```

You need some flat data structure to read the query result from.

```
private class CustomerContract 
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set;}
    public string ContractId { get; set;}
    public int NumberOfProducts { get; set;}
}
```

After reading the result set to that flat data structures you can group by customer Id and convert to the data structure you need.

```
var result = customerContract.GroupBy(item => item.CustomerName)
                             .Select(group => new Customer {
                                                  Name = group.CustomerName,
                                                  Contracts = group.Select(
                                                       e => new Contract {
                                                           Id = e.ContractId,
                                                           NumberOfProducts = e.NumberOfProducts
                                                       }
                                                  ).ToList()
                                              })
                             .ToList();
```

Comment: Though this might be correct it is a shame posting an answer when no effort has been done and it is even not clear if it is querying a DB or a json file

Comment: It's so shame of me :( i must confest

Answer (score 1):

You can create and populate the list of Customer as,

```
List<Customer> lstCustomer = new List<Customer>()
            {
                new Customer(){customer="1", ls_contract=new List<Contract>()
                {
                    new Contract(){contract_id="HD2", number_of_products="1000"},
                    new Contract(){contract_id="HD3", number_of_products="4500"},
                    new Contract(){contract_id="HD4", number_of_products="20000"}
                } },
                new Customer(){customer="2", ls_contract=new List<Contract>()
                {
                    new Contract(){contract_id="HD5", number_of_products="70"},
                    new Contract(){contract_id="HD6", number_of_products="8000"},
                } },
                new Customer(){customer="3", ls_contract=new List<Contract>()
                {
                    new Contract(){contract_id="HD7", number_of_products="660"},
                    new Contract(){contract_id="HD8", number_of_products="2200"},
                } }


            };
```

Comment: NOTE: write class names as "Customer" and "Contract"  ==> class names must be different from its member names